# How to configure Selenium+GitHub+Jenkins

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium2, java, jenkins

I was trying to configure Selenium+GitHub+Jenkins but unable to do it, I was able to configure selenium and Jenkins but not with GitHub.

We need to build in same workspace where is my code if not, then how to change the build path.

***I want to run the selenium scripts when new push committed to git-hub and jenkins should execute the scripts.***

Comment: What specific problems or errors are you getting.  This site is intended for _specific_ questions that can have _specific_ answers to them.  Please imagine trying to answer you have posed - what questions would one be answering?  "Suggestions" other than read and study the field don't help .

Comment: Updated. If you know how to do it (How to configure Selenium+GitHub+Jenkins) then please let me know.

Comment: @Michael Durrant, TESTasy, Yu Zhang, NarendraC, Bharat Mane - Guys If I ask issue then some people will say post your issue in detail and some people ask for setup and few people will ask for code, then tell me how to post the question?. _Just my issue is unable to configure "Selenium+GitHub+Jenkins"_, if you know then please suggest the blogs or your valuable answer for this please hope you wont mind :).

Comment: I Agree........ I think people are expecting this question instead of long question"_I want to run the selenium scripts when new push committed to git-hub and jenkins should execute the scripts._"

Comment: **Updated the question.**

Comment: 1) Specify github project url 2) Specify the git repository (URL) 3) Specify polling (SCM) 4) Build (Root POM) pom.xml or bat file. 5) Check build is working or not 6) Change the script and push to git and as per polling/scm scripts will run.

Comment: @Sachin, thanks a lot it's working fine...!!!!!